# i want to send an emails to a customer through marketing cloud using php script.

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

What are the necessary things are needed to send an emails through marketing cloud using php script.

Answer (score 4):

There are several different ways to send emails using marketing cloud. If you just want to send one individual email, you could initiate a triggered send using the FuelSDK-PHP.

You need to create the triggered send first, then activate it and note down the ID of your triggered send. This ID is then used in your PHP code to trigger the email send using the FuelSDK.

The creation wizard for a triggered send can be found in *Email Studio* under *Interactions > Messages > Email > Triggered > Create*.

If you subscribers haven't been added to All Subscribers list yet, you need to enable the "Add subscribers to this list" feature in order for the send to be successful. Otherwise the send would fail as there are no valid subscribers for the subscriber data.

In order to use the API you need a client ID and secret, which can be obtained in AppCenter. These credentials need to be provided in the PHP code.

**Resources:**

- [Create a Triggered Email Message Interaction](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_triggered_email_interaction.htm&type=5)
- [API Integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm)
- [FuelSDK-PHP](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP)
- [TriggeredSend Sample](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP/blob/master/objsamples/sample-triggeredsend.php)